# Can I have `join` and `with` together in laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I have `users` table, every user can have many skills :

```
 $user = User::with('Skill')->where('id',1)->first();
```

No problem so far! and I can use skill like this :

```
$user->Skill->name
```

There  are many other tables that are belong to user  e.g. (company,color ...) and I want to use them just once in my controller so I don't want to create a relation function in User model

what I want is to have a query like this :

```
$user = User::with('Skill')
            ->leftJoin('companies', function ($join) use ($id) {
                $join->on('companies.user_id','=' ,'users.id');
                $join->where('users.id', '=',$id);
            })
            ->leftJoin('colors', function ($join) use ($id) {
                $join->on('colors.user_id','=' ,'users.id');
                $join->where('users.id', '=',$id);
            })
            ->first();
```

But it gives me `$user` information with empty profile and no color and no company!

Do I have to put `Skill` model in join instead of `with()` too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can load multiple relationships

```php
App\User::with('skill', 'country', 'color')->first();
```

Here is a sample output in the tinker

```
=> App\User {#666
     id: "1",
     name: "Gussie Rice DVM",
     email: "delfina.treutel@example.org",
     created_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
     updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
     skill: App\Skill {#662
       id: "1",
       name: "mollitia",
       user_id: "1",
       created_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
       updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
     },
     country: App\Country {#667
       id: "1",
       name: "Sierra Leone",
       user_id: "1",
       created_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
       updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
     },
     color: App\Color {#669
       id: "1",
       name: "Brown",
       user_id: "1",
       created_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
       updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:09:43",
     },
   }
```

In this example all relationships are one-to-one but they as easily could've been one-to-many.

```php
App\User::with('skills', 'countries', 'colors')->first();
```

**UPDATE:**

> As I said in the question I want to use them just once in my controller so I don't want to create a relation function in User model. ( Do I have to do that?)...

**TL;DR**

What you're trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense in this particular case because it's more verbose, less obvious, more prone to errors, hard to maintain as opposed to **eloquent idiomatic** way, which is two super short very clear relationship functions in a `User` model and then a one-liner in a controller that fetches a user and loads all three relationships.

**The long explanation**

Using `with` and joins is totally fine as long as you disambiguate column names in the resulting set. Otherwise values for the columns with the same name will be overwritten by the rightmost non null value when the model instance will be created. To clarify in your case when you join three tables (users -> companies -> colors) and all of them have the `name` column you'll get a `User` instance back with the name set to the color name if it isn't `null`.

Let me illustrate. If we run your query, which I omitting for brevity, we get the following back

```
=> App\User {#871
     id: "1",
     name: "Tomato", // <-- color name instead of the user name
     email: "walter.elyse@example.org",
     created_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
     updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
     user_id: "1",
     skill: App\Skill {#873
       id: "1",
       name: "tempora",
       user_id: "1",
       created_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
       updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
     },
   }
```

See how in the returned `User` model you have the name set to the color name instead of the user name

You need to explicitly define names for ambitious columns:

```php
App\User::with('skill')->leftJoin('companies', function ($join) use ($id) 
    join->on('companies.user_id','=' ,'users.id');
    $join->on('users.id', '=',$id);
})->leftJoin('colors', function ($join) use ($id) {
    $join->on('colors.user_id','=' ,'users.id');
    $join->on('users.id', '=', $id);
})->select(
    'users.*', 
    'companies.name as company_name', // <--
    'colors.name as color_name' // <--
)->first();
```

Which will give you

```
=> App\User {#885
     id: "1",
     name: "Kareem Mante", // <-- users.name
     email: "walter.elyse@example.org",
     created_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
     updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
     company_name: "Renner Group", // <- companies.name
     color_name: "Tomato", // <-- colors.name
     skill: App\Skill {#887
       id: "1",
       name: "tempora",
       user_id: "1",
       created_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
       updated_at: "2017-02-10 19:34:51",
     },
   }
```

**Now** the only case where you may want to use joins is if you return back a big resulting set and want to avoid having 4 separate queries (one for each model/table).

Comment: Thank you @peterm !   As I said in the question  I want to use them just once in my controller so I don't want to create a relation function in User model.  ( Do I have to do that?) . OR the other way is : just having  `joins` not `with()` I can go with this way too. But can't I have them together? (`join` and `with`)

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki See the updated answer with explanations. But in short you don't want to do this.